# WPF: Button which is a path

Tags: c#, wpf, button, path

I have a bunch of `Button`s in my application which look almost the same. The only difference between them is the path data that they use.

This is the style I have for the "minimize button" of my application:

```
<Style x:Key="MinimizeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <!-- The border is here to make the entire "block" clickable.
                     Without it, only the actual path is clickable. -->
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <Path Name="ThePath" Data="{StaticResource MinimizeIconPath}" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonPath}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, I'm basically just changing the control template to use a path instead of the default button stuff. But this declaration is *only for the minimize button* – I have a few other buttons, such as "maximize", "restore" and "close" to deal with now. The problem is that the styles for those buttons will be *identical*, with the only difference being the `Data` attribute of their `Path`s.

What would you recommend me to do to use as little code as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User control?

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c12521/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XSButton.aspx

Comment: The first link is broken.